# how to pass parameter to dictionary input for agg pyspark function

Tags: python, pyspark

From the [pyspark docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.GroupedData.agg.html), I Can do:

```
gdf = df.groupBy(df.name)
sorted(gdf.agg({"*": "first"}).collect())
```

In my actual use case I have maaaany variables, so I like that I can simply create a dictionary, which is why:

```
gdf = df.groupBy(df.name)
sorted(gdf.agg(F.first(col, ignorenulls=True)).collect())
```

@lemon's suggestion won't work for me.

How can I pass a parameter for `first` (i.e. `ignorenulls=True`), see [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.first.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use list comprehension.

```py
gdf.agg(*[F.first(x, ignorenulls=True).alias(x) for x in df.columns]).collect()
```

Answer (score 2):

Try calling the `pyspark` function directly:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

gdf = df.groupBy(df.name)

parameters = {'col': <your_column_name, 'ignorenulls': True}
sorted(gdf.agg(F.first(**parameters)).collect())
```

Does it work for you?

ps. `ignorenulls`' is True by default.

Comment: this works yes ,but I have a large list of variables so I want the dict way actually ,will clarify this in my question

Comment: @safex I've updated the answer with the required generalization on the function parameter values. If you need also a generalization on the name of the function, you can do it using a call by name. For that, take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-of-a-module-by-using-its-name-a-string.